# GRUB2: adding insmod xxxx module in the grub.cfg properly

Tags: linux, centos, grub2, grub

I want to add my own custom grub2 module, for ex. xxxx.mod into the grub.cfg. How can I do that?
For example, here i want to add 
insmod xxxx.mod below:

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry 'CentOS Linux, with Linux 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64' --class centos     --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --unrestricted     $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64-advanced-de1018ee-c601-4d48-9e1b-042a7ec8d6c1' {
load_video
set gfxpayload=keep
insmod gzio
insmod part_msdos 
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos5'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5 --hint='hd0,msdos5'  de1018ee-c601-4d48-9e1b-042a7ec8d6c1
else
```

Comment: a kernel module?

Comment: No, a grub2 module.